# UILabel in CollectionViewCell not blocking touch events

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit

**What I Have**

- A is a `UICollectionView`
- B is a `UICollectionViewCell`
- C is a `UILabel` subview of B

  ```
  +------------------------------+
  |A                             |
  |                              |
  | +----------+    +----------+ |
  | |C         |    |B         | |
  | |----------|    |          | |
  | |          |    |          | |
  | |B         |    |          | |
  | +----------+    +----------+ |
  +------------------------------+
  ```

When tapping on B, C is added to the top of the cell as a subview. When tapping again on B, C is removed from the superview (B).

**Issue**

Touch events "fall through" C to B.

**I cannot seem to find how to ignore / block these touch events; i.e., tapping on the `UILabel` C should not propagate down the responder chain.**

For example if C were a `UIButton`, a `UICollectionView`, etc. it would automatically "intercept" touch events. How so? They all inherit from `UIResponder` as `UIView`s...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `UILabel` has no user interaction - so it doesn't "intercept" touches.

If you set `.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` on your `C` label, it *should* "eat" the touches.

**Edit:** After quick testing *with an actual collection view cell* ... you also need to add a Gesture Recognizer to the label to "eat" the touches. Subclassing the label worked for me in my (new, improved) quick test:

```
class EatTouchesLabel: UILabel {

    var myGest: UIGestureRecognizer!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        self.commonInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        if myGest == nil {
            myGest = UITapGestureRecognizer()
            self.addGestureRecognizer(myGest)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: first thing I tried but it does not work which is driving me crazy. My `UILabel` is set programmatically with autolayout, does that change anything?

Comment: Are you sure your `UILabel` is actually *above* `B` in the view hierarchy? Can you set background colors and post a screen-cap of how it looks? I'm doing a quick test of overlaying a label on a button, and if the `. isUserInteractionEnabled` is set to false, the button gets the touch... when true, nope. So....?

Comment: awesome stuff, works perfect and should have thought about it. Tried to override and implement a custom `hitTest` func in the cell but couldn't achieve what I wanted. This is much simpler and clearer. Thanks !